# Corona SDK - crash after run simulator

Tags: coronasdk

At first time when I was used Corona all work fine. But in some time after run I get error

`The stdin connection has closed corona sdk`

I am tried install new/older version and install new driver for video card there not working.

Need help, pls!

Comment: put up your code please!

Comment: Is your Java the right version?

Comment: JRE and JDK version 1.8, add path to enviroment variables

Comment: Youshould be around 8 not 1?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution!
Problem was in video card. I have Intel processor and Radeon video card. I think that is a conflict. I disable vide card driver and all work fine!